# Find common elements in large files

Tags: python

I have 2 text files that are about 50-100 GB. i tried writing a code that can check if a same element is present in 2 file what i mean by this is lets say txt file 1 has numbers from 1 to 100 and file 2 has numbers from 98 to 500 so since 99 and 100 is print in both the files i need the code to display what's the common element present in both the file.

i tried wring this code

```
def check_elements(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
        elements = set(f1.read().split())

    with open(file2, 'r') as f2:
        content = f2.read()
        num_elements = len(elements)
        progress_step = max(num_elements // 100, 1)
        progress = 0
        for i, element in enumerate(elements):
            if element in content:
                return True
            if i % progress_step == 0:
                progress += 1
                print(f"Progress: {progress}%")

    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if check_elements('c.txt', 'Info_sec.txt'):
        print('At least one element from c.txt is present in Info_sec.txt')
    else:
        print ('No elements from c.txt are present in Info_sec.txt')
```

But since the file is 50-100 GB i'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\checker\rage.py", line 21, in <module>
    if check_elements('c.txt', 'Info_sec.txt'):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\checker\rage.py", line 3, in check_elements
    elements = set(f1.read().split())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
MemoryError
```

How do i fix this what wrong am i doing? and how can i make it search much faster?

**Thank you @zoldxk your solution works but the problem is its not locating the element. the element in file1 looks like 0x000000000000000000000000000545df2097e0f826927d3844dcfbe5fa639cfa4 | 6GyV5TcP6fb5V7iYZvn1U4SrFmYrsU34ur and the element in file2 looks like 6GyV5TcP6fb5V7iYZvn1U4SrFmYrsU34ur # + 40000000000000000000000000 and here in both the files the common element is "6GyV5TcP6fb5V7iYZvn1U4SrFmYrsU34ur " how do i rectify this ?**

Comment: What is the structure of the files? Maybe if the numbers are on separate lines you can use `set(f1)` instead? Also, the second file can be read into a set too and you can do set intersection instead.

Comment: Are both files really 50-100 GB, or is one (Info_sec.txt?) much smaller?

Comment: @AndrejKesely, oof, say bye to your RAM. :^)

Comment: @doneforaiur Why? The first file has numbers only from 0 - 100, so the set would have 100 elements max

Comment: @AndrejKesely "lets say txt file 1 has numbers from 1 to 100 " - doesn't sound that's their real data.

Comment: Checkout the [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure, which allows the memory efficient storage of lots of strings with performant membership querying. There are python packages out there that implement StringTries like [pytrie](https://github.com/google/pygtrie). You could load one file into a trie and then query the elements of the other against it. Trie uses common prefixes/substrings to save space, so with millions of words that usually saves a lot.

Comment: You can narrow down the candidates by comparing the first few characters of each line or the hash value. Or you could sort both files first and then compare one line at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to load the entire contents of the file into memory using `read()` ( 50 Gb can't fit in your RAM), I suggest you to use an iterative approach where you read the files line by line :

```
def check_elements(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
        words = set(word.strip() for line in f1 for word in line.split())

    with open(file2, 'r') as f2:
        for line in f2:
            words_in_line = set(word.strip() for word in line.split())
            common_words = words_in_line.intersection(words)
            if common_words:
                return True

    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if check_elements('c.txt', 'Info_sec.txt'):
        print('At least one word from c.txt is present in Info_sec.txt')
    else:
        print('No words from c.txt are present in Info_sec.txt')
```

Comment: This approach would also "load" `file1` into the memory. Also, this function returns `True` if even a single element is common.

Comment: @doneforaiur No it would not load the whole `file1` into a memory. The second claim is however true.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, oh yeah, they are adding it to a set, my bad. :^)

Comment: I updated my code, but it was just an example

Comment: Thank you @zoldxk  your solution works but the problem is its not locating the element.  the element in file1 looks like 0x000000000000000000000000000545df2097e0f826927d3844dcfbe5fa639cfa4 | 6GyV5TcP6fb5V7iYZvn1U4SrFmYrsU34ur and the element in file2 looks like 6GyV5TcP6fb5V7iYZvn1U4SrFmYrsU34ur # + 40000000000000000000000000   and here in both the files the common element is "6GyV5TcP6fb5V7iYZvn1U4SrFmYrsU34ur "  how do i rectify this ?

Comment: can you update your question to clarify things